# How can I setup a session idle event in Amazon LexV2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I'm building a bot in Amazon LexV2 and I use a lambda function for intents and works well. Now I have a requirement to show a final message with a short yes/no question when the user is idle.

How can I accomplish this?

I was planning to use another lambda function to be launched whenever a user is idle, show the message and store the answer in a Dynamo table. Looking on internet for clarification I couldn't find anything concrete.

I even asked ChatGPT and Google Bard but the instructions where outdated, they mentioned something like "Under Session expiration select Send a Lambda function", but I couldn't find that setting.